# Spring Boot 2, Separate AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

First I wanted to point out I'm a bit frustrated already as I spent almost a week on my "problem" looking for some REAL solution over the StackOverflow, github and wherever possible but still can't find anything reasonable (f$%#ck!!)

What I'm trying to do is im developing a solution consisting of few components:

1. Separate authorization server with OAuth2 and JWT (with authorization_code flow),
2. Separate resource server that is using mentioned authorization server as an authentication provider (?),
3. Front end app that is consuming apis from both of servers, ideally a Single Page Application.

What I was trying are some of those git repositories as an examples:

- https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2-vanilla
- https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth

First one seemed promissing but its based on Spring boot 1, I was not successful in converting it into Spring boot 2 project.

Second one is based on Spring boot 2 but didn't provide me what I really wanted...

Please, I'm begging you, can anyone point me out a complete and comprehensive tutorial/git repo with solution that actually WORKS? ;(

Answer (score 1):

I'll point you to what I've used for my own project. I've had to adapt it a bit to my needs as there's a somewhat more complex structure to my project but it does the job.

https://github.com/in28minutes/full-stack-with-angular-and-spring-boot/tree/master/restful-web-services/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/rest/webservices/restfulwebservices/jwt

If it helps, this is currently (in modified form) providing the JWT authentication for our application, front end is an Angular app, back end is Spring Boot 2, and it's honestly working wonderfully for us.

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

My tutorial might help - and the write ups - the important thing is understanding the OAuth standards - once you know what you want you can do it in any technology ..
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/